Replace ALL XML attributes for all entries
I have been trying to replace all values for a particular XML attribute for all entries.
I have XML like this:
<Attributes>
  <Entry key="T2" value="r1" />
  <Entry key="Test" value="s1" />
</Attributes>

It may have any number of 'Entry' tag and every 'Entry' tag has two attributes: 'key' and 'value' (any values are possible there).
My goal is to replace all values in the attribute 'value' to blank.
The desired result:
<Attributes>
  <enter code hereEntry key="T2" value="" />
  <Entry key="Test" value="" />
</Attributes>

And know already that I can't use this:
replace value of (Attributes/Entry/@value) with "" (it returns more that one result)
or this
replace value of (Attributes/Entry/@value)[{sql:variable("@i")}] with "" (OMG, SQL injection is here).
So what is the best (and possible) way to do this operation?

Your second solution isn't SQL Injection.

Either loop or deconstruct your xml and reconstruct it with empty value, this might be somewhat complicated if you have many tags

WHILE 1=1 BEGIN UPDATE ...... WHERE xmlcolumn.exists('XqueryToModify') = 1; IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 BREAK; END;
